# I use image and text side by side in footer but it creates problem when window is resized

Tags: css

Image after resize:

[image]

I use this code in my footer section. I have an image and some content side by side using media object class in bootstrap 4, but when the window is resized, the image and the content do not remain same and it creates a problem.

Here is my code:

```
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6  mt-5"> 
        <h5>Product</h5>
 <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left">
           <a href="#"><img class="media-object" 
  src="./assets/Img/prod.png" alt="..."></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
           <h6><a href="#">vulputate velit consequat. </a></h6>
           <div class="text-primary">
            <i class="far fa-star"></i>
            <i class="far fa-star"></i>
            <i class="far fa-star"></i>
            <i class="far fa-star"></i>
            <i class="far fa-star"></i>
        </div>
        <span><s>Rs1200.00</s> Rs1000.00 </span>
     </div>
       
                
      

      </div>
      </div>
```

Image I actually want:

[image]

Comment: Is this a bootstrap 3 or 4 ?

Comment: This is bootstrap 4

Comment: Please [edit] your question to:
clarify title of question, improve code formatting, include the current result, include the expected result,
 provide more information about the problem: 
screenshots
,
 and anything else that can help us solve your problem.
See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind using only CSS instead of using Bootstrap? If no, then you may check out this answer. I have written the code in pure HTML and CSS:

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #2F2F2F;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
}

.img1 {
  width: 20%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title of the page</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2 style="padding: 10px;">Product</h2>
    <img src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/09e55b5e6a65a3ba9e38ed4de0f96ddd8ad46ba5c57b3e94d05222e0f127402a/68747470733a2f2f662e636c6f75642e6769746875622e636f6d2f6173736574732f323037383234352f3235393331332f35653833313336322d386362612d313165322d383435332d6536626439353663383961342e706e67"
      class="img1">
    <p>vulputate velit consequat</p>
    <h3>&#11088;&#11088;&#11088;&#11088;&#11088;</h3>
    <span><s>Rs 1200</s> Rs 1000</span>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```